# symfony 3 console command list in controller

Tags: symfony, controller, command

As I am not sure how to describe it, I didn't found any results in google or stack.

I would like to list all available console commands (which are callable by using the bin/console) with a Controller-Action so that I can forward a list of all commands to twig.

How can I realize this ?

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458501/symfony-doctrine-get-list-of-available-commands ?

Comment: @DylanKas not relevant to the question because he wants to display them in a twig template!

Comment: So ? Using this in a twig extension would help rendering it in a twig template

Comment: I need the Console commands for adding a user function which makes console commands (cronjobs) callable manually whenever. 
So, I don not really display them, but I need the value of it, thats why I said I use them in twig (controller, twig, all the same :))

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  You can of course just run the console command itself and capture the list of commands.  Might actually be the best way.

However, there is a service called `console.command_loader` which has a method called getNames which does indeed return a list of command names.  It implements CommandLoaderInterface.

Originally I tried to create an alias so it could be injected into an action method:

```
services:
   Symfony\Component\Console\CommandLoader\CommandLoaderInterface: 
       alias: console.command_loader
```

But I kept getting console.command_loader not found which was puzzling since debug:container shows it.  The service was tagged with `container.no_preload` which might have something to do with it.  Not sure.

So I went and just defined the controller service:

```
services:
    App\Controller\CommandController:
        tags:
            - 'controller.service_arguments'
        arguments:
            - '@console.command_loader'
```

And somewhat to my surprise it worked.

```
class CommandController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(private CommandLoaderInterface $cl)
    {
    }
   
    #[Route('/commands', name: 'app_commands')]
    public function commands(): Response
    {
        $names = $this->cl->getNames();
        dump($names);

        // I happen to have a command called app:init
        $initCommand = $this->cl->get('app:init');
        dump($initCommand->getDescription());

        //return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        //    'controller_name' => 'DefaultController ' . 'Commands',
        //]);
    }
}
```

This was all done in Symfony 6.  Did not happen to have a Symfony 3 app handy.  Your first step would be to confirm that Symfony 3 also has the service with `bin/console debug:container console.command_loader`.  If it does not have such a service then poke around a bit and see if it has something similar.

Comment: Thank you Cerad for your explanation and your snippets. This is it!

Comment: Thank you for the thank you but stackoverflow tends to frown upon `thank you` type comments.  On the other hand, accepting an answer makes it clear that the answer did the trick and strongly implies a thank you..